# How to avoid using Multidex in rather simple android app?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, android-multidex

I'm developing a rather simple app with not that many dependencies (but some are quite complex) and while developing I reached a point where the app can't get built anymore because the maximum number of classes in a non-Multidex app is reached (maximum number is 65.536).

I've always been using `minifyEnabled true` (otherwise I would have near to 80.000 rather than my current 68.822 classes), my app size is around 11MB (installed).

What can I do to reduce the number of methods even further to avoid using Multidex?
Should I use the `exclude` term in my `build.gradle` files?
Or should I adapt my proguard rules?

*Here are my build.gradle configs of the app module*:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:bottomsheets:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.cyb3rko:about-icons:master-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries-core:8.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:8.3.0'
    implementation 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And these are the sources for the gradle plugins:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "com.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.plugin:aboutlibraries-plugin:8.3.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: without being rude or trying to take away from the different authors, are you sure you really need all these libraries ? they might make life easier, but they are an external dependency and add additional resources and classes to your project. do you really need a library for dialogs ? for toasts ? to create an about page?

Comment: 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1' this library, as far as i can tell, seems to be 4+ years old. perhaps material components has something built in which is similar (or better). this is all just something to consider

Comment: "And these are the project wide dependencies" -- no, they are sources of Gradle plugins. "What can I do to reduce the number of methods even further to avoid using Multidex?" -- while the support multidex has security issues, that's only needed on Android 4.4 and older. Android 5.0+ has native multidex support. Certainly aiming to have a smaller app is fine, but what is the specific concern regarding multidex?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yeah, they are really making life easier. E.g. the Material Dialog library replaces writing a new file with many of lines for dialogfragment with an easy call (which has maybe 5-10 lines), that's because it's one of the most used android libraries out there. But I don't really think that they are game-changing. I mean there are still 3.000 classes which are too much, and all those simple libraries you mentioned together only have a handful of classes. Does that change anything?

Comment: "and all those simple libraries you mentioned together only have a handful of classes" -- they might have only a few classes directly. However, they will have transitive dependencies that will pull in additional libraries, which might be small or might be large.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, corrected that, thanks! Some say that you should try to avoid using Multiplex because it's adding extra complexity to your app. Is there really no way to further reduce the size?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I already analyzed the used dependencies and exluded some transitive dependencies in build.gradle, but that did not reduce the number of used classes by even one?

Comment: "Some say that you should try to avoid using Multiplex because it's adding extra complexity to your app" -- I have not heard that complaint in years, FWIW. "Is there really no way to further reduce the size?" -- as a_local_nobody indicated, remove libraries. "exluded some transitive dependencies" -- usually, you cannot do that and still have the library working. The library developer had those transitive dependencies for a reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I tested it by removing "Toasty". It didn't reduce the number by even one because it only uses, as I have just seen, only "appcompat" dependency. I think there is nothing to optimize, I think I will have to use Multiplex. Thanks for your time!